# Skip is not currently supported by the Data Service tool kit exception

Tags: asp.net, linq, webforms

I am trying to query oDataService. If I try skip, I get "Skip is not currently supported by the Data Service tool kit" exception. Without skip, my query gets executed.

```
Dim Students = S in Entity.Students
               Select S
               OrderBy S.FirstName
               Skip(PageSize * PageNumber).Take(PageSize)
```

If I leave Take, it still works. How can I fix this? Is there a different way to do pagination in linq?

Comment: That error is thrown by LINQ providers that do not support whichever extension method you are trying to use. In this case, it means that the Data Service tool kit just does not support the Skip method. Your only solution is to: Take(PageSize * PageNumber + PageSize).ToList().Skip(PageSize * PageNumber)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I get "Unable to cast object of type '<SkipIterator>" exception with you code.

Comment: OK. Adding another ToList() after the call to Skip() usually solves that.

Comment: No luck. Now I get "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List" exception.

Comment: Is there more to the exception message? Typically, it will tell you that it is unable to cast object of type 'whatever' to 'something else'.

Comment: yeah.. It can't cast object to " type 'System.Linq.IQueryable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me provide the answer here for clarity and to make sure the code is clearer.

That error is thrown by LINQ providers that do not support whichever extension method you are trying to use. In this case, it means that the Data Service tool kit just does not support the Skip method. Your only solution is to get everything up through the number of items you want, then skip those you don't need. This does require you to force LINQ to execute the query and return all the data to you as a list first.

```
Dim BatchStudents = S in Entity.Students
                    Select S
                    OrderBy S.FirstName
                    Take(PageSize * PageNumber + PageSize).ToList()

Dim Students = BatchStudents.Skip(PageSize * PageNumber).ToList()
```

Breaking these up into separate statements (and variables) will help track down any further issues with casting.

**Warning**: Doing this as-is will retrieve PageSize * PageNumber + PageSize items from the data source, so expect a large download of that remote data as the page number increases. This is only because the provider does not support skipping. The first ToList() forces LINQ to execute the query and get the results. The second variable assignment is skipping items in memory (the items are already downloaded).

Comment: With the above code, are you still getting the cast exception?

Comment: It worked thanks. It works when I put the skip part in a new variable.

Comment: Glad to hear it. I will add another bit of warning to the answer for you and others though.